# setOnItemClickListener does not work

Tags: android, listview, onitemclicklistener

I'm having some problems to figure out how I can implement '.setOnItemClickListener' in a GitHub sample project for Android.

I want to select the cells of a list view, but I can get it to work. The github project is this:

https://github.com/schrockblock/android-table-view

I'm trying to add the listener in my main activity but I can't. Here is the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

public String[] items={};
WifiHelper wifiHelper;
List<ScanResult> list;
//public WifiManager pWifiManager;
ListView tableView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // 取得WifiManager对象
    //pWifiManager = (WifiManager) this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

    wifiHelper = new WifiHelper(this);

    //open wifi
    wifiHelper.openWifi(new WifiHelper.openWifiCallback() {
        @Override
        public void openSuccess() {
            //open success

        }

        @Override
        public void openFail() {
            //open fail

        }
    });

    //scan wifi
    list = wifiHelper.startScan();

    tableView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.table_view);
    TableViewDataSource tvds = new TableViewDataSource(this){

        @Override
        protected int numberOfSections() {
            return 3;
        }

        @Override
        protected String titleForHeaderInSection(int section) {
            if(section==0)
                return "\nGENERAL";
            else if(section==1)
                return "Pull down to refresh networks information ot tap 'Scan' button in the top bar of the screen.\n\nNETWORKS";
            else
                return "Networks under -75dB (RSSI) may have connectivity problems. Try to be as near as you can of the network.\n\nOnly supported networks can use the exploit feature of this app. You can use iWepPRO as your wifi manager application";
        }

        @Override
        protected int numberOfRowsInSection(int section){
            if(section==0)
                return 3;
            else if(section==1)
                return list.size();
            else
                return 1;
        }

        @Override
        protected DefaultCell cellForRowAtIndexPath(JIndexPath indexPath) {

            if(indexPath.section==0) {
                DefaultCell cell = new DefaultCell();
                cell.hashIBencryption = true;
                cell.imageButtonImage = R.drawable.emptywhite2px;

                switch (indexPath.row){
                    case 0:
                        cell.textLabelText = "WiFi";
                        cell.hasDisclosureIndicator = false;
                        cell.hasDisclosureIndicator2 = false;
                        cell.hasSwitch = true;
                        cell.hasSwitchOn = true;
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        cell.textLabelText = "Auto-Scan";
                        cell.hasDisclosureIndicator = false;
                        cell.hasDisclosureIndicator2 = false;
                        cell.hasSwitch = true;
                        cell.hasSwitchOn = false;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        cell.textLabelText = "Information";
                        cell.hasDisclosureIndicator = true;
                        cell.hasDisclosureIndicator2 = false;
                        break;

                    default:
                        break;
                }

                return cell;

            }else if(indexPath.section==1){
                SubtitleCell cell1 = new SubtitleCell();
                cell1.hasDisclosureIndicator = false;
                cell1.hasDisclosureIndicator2 = true;
                cell1.hashIBencryption = true;
                //cell1.textLabelText = "network name " + indexPath.row;
                ScanResult r = list.get(indexPath.row);
                //String ssidName = r.SSID;
                cell1.textLabelText = r.SSID;
                //cell1.detailTextLabelText = "signal " + indexPath.row;
                cell1.detailTextLabelText = "" + r.level;
                //cell1.detailTextLabelText = "" + calculateSignalStength(pWifiManager, r.level);
                cell1.imageButtonImage = R.drawable.deviceaccesssecure;
                return cell1;

            }else if(indexPath.section==2){
                SubtitleCell cell2 = new SubtitleCell();
                cell2.hashIBencryption = true;
                cell2.imageButtonImage = R.drawable.emptywhite2px;
                cell2.textLabelText = " ";
                cell2.hasDisclosureIndicator2 = false;
                cell2.hasDisclosureIndicator = false;
                cell2.hasEmptyCell = true;

                return  cell2;

            }

            return null;
        }

    };

    tableView.setAdapter(tvds);

}
```

I have read and test some samples coding the setOnItemClickListener after the 'setAdapter()' function, but it does not work.

I 'm trying to set the cell selection to show a Toast with some text in order to see if it works, but I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Can anyone help me with some tips??

Thank you very much in advance.

These are my two layouts:

Cell Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/rl"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:padding="0dp"
android:background="#ffdedede">

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/header_text_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:textSize="12dp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:padding="0dp" 
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:typeface="sans"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:elegantTextHeight="false" />

<RelativeLayout 
android:id="@+id/rl2"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/header_text_view"
android:padding="0dp"
    android:background="@android:color/white">

<RelativeLayout 
android:id="@+id/rl3"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="0dp"
    android:background="@android:color/white">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/title_text_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Cell Title"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:background="#0fff"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="2dp"
        android:typeface="sans"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ibencryption"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/ibencryption" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/detail_text_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Cell Subtitle"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:textColor="#555"
    android:background="#0fff"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ibencryption"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/ibencryption" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/ibencryption"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="false" />
</RelativeLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/disclosure_indicator"
    android:src="@drawable/nextitem"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:cropToPadding="true"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/disclosure_indicator_2"
    android:src="@drawable/actionabout"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:cropToPadding="true"/>

<Switch
    android:id="@+id/switch_indicator"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:cropToPadding="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And the main activity layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/table_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Thank you!!

Comment: i recommand you to do it in the [Android Way](http://www.android-ios-tutorials.com/android/android-custom-listview-example/)

Comment: Your problem might resides in UI blocking views, can you please post your xml layout for the listview cell

Comment: hi, I have remove some 'false' options like 'clickable' and 'focusable', in order to test it, but it keeps doing the same.

Comment: I have test the initial project and the setOnItemClickListener works perfectly. So I think Johan is right, I'm gonna try to depurate it and refactor my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you can provide a OnItemClickListener :

```
tableView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
switch(position){
default: Toast.makeToast(MainActivity.this, "Some crappy text",Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
}

}
 }};
```

Generally :

First of all put all your `View#findViewById(int)` code to the top of your OnCreate method just below your `Activity#setContentView(int)` call.
Then try to scan in your WifiManager#openSuccess() callback..

Try to refactor your code and replace all your if,else if and else blocks which check against an integer with switch blocks.
And please do not return null **EVER**.

Comment: I have tried it but keeps doing the same, it does not work. I have tested the original project and the method works properly. So I'm gonna debug it.

Comment: The problem was when I add a button the cell. Then the cell stops responding to setOnItemClickListener... So, what do I have to do ignored to be able to tap in both items???

Comment: You are setting an OnItemClickListener here which will respond on a click event on the whole surface of your list view item. If you want each individual View to respond you should setOnItemClickListeners in the adapter on the given views.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I have solve it adding `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` to the main layout. Now I can use the setOnClickListener to every row of the listView.

Comment: You don't need to. Just don't add the OnItemClickListener